# Webcam has Cheese effect EVERYWHERE, even on other OS

Tags: dual-boot, webcam

Okay, so this is going to sound very strange, and I have no logical explanation for it.

So, I was using the builtin Cheese webcam booth to mess around with some effects. That was fine.

Then, later, I'm not sure exactly when, I tried to use the webcam elsewhere, and, lo and behold, the effect I had active in Cheese was still active on the webcam. I've rebooted, reinstalled Cheese (and the gnome-video-effects package), and it has persisted. And, today, I discovered that it was much worse than I thought. I booted into my windows dual boot, and the problem persisted.

However, when I plug in an external webcam, there is no problem. The other camera works perfectly.

So, is there any logical explanation for this, and is there any way I can remedy it?

HARDWARE: Dell Insipiron 15 7559

EDIT: I have noticed that sometimes the unedited camera feed can be seen, especially when the camera has just been activated.

Comment: Did you try checking with the computer manufacturer to see if they might have an explanation for it?

Comment: @Terrance No, I have not. I'm also not sure they would be willing to help because of my dual-boot situation. Also, it is most definitely the result of either something I did or a software error, as it worked before.

Comment: I don't know what your hardware is on your system, but it sounds like the webcam might have some type of memory / firmware that might be susceptible to saving a setting like this.

Comment: Have you checked to see if anyone else out there with the same hardware as you has had the same effect?

Comment: Added hardware to question. I have googled as many phrasings as I can think of, and I haven't found anything.

Comment: I just don't see how settings from Ubuntu would have any effect on Windows itself unless it was able to save directly to the Windows setting.  Try a full power reset on your laptop to see if that has any effect on it.  A full power reset is pulling all power from the laptop, even the main battery.  Push the power button a few times with no power connected.  Then reconnect the power and power it back up.  That should clear any capacitance for memory in the device that might be stored between reboots.

Comment: Battery is internal. I will try pulling out the battery cable. I'm busy at the moment, but I will try later. Also, it might not be designed to even try to power on without battery.

Comment: Have you perhaps opened cheese and turned the effect off?

Comment: Yes. It shows with the effect even under "no effect." I also just noticed that it does pop up normally for a second before the effect is applied, which would suggest that the effect is software-based or maybe firmware-based.

Comment: I will try letting the battery run down and then starting it up.

Comment: That failed. Dang it.